# mount command times out when trying to mount between servers

Tags: mount, nfs, redhat-enterprise-linux

I've got two identical RHEL boxes and would like to mount a directory from one to the other.

my command:

```
[me@serv_dev ~]$ sudo mount serv_prod:/my/dir /mnt/my/dir
```

times out after a few minutes:

```
mount: mount to NFS server 'eseweb.sats.corp' failed: System Error: Connection timed out.
```

I can ping and log on to `serv_prod` with my username. Ensured `/mnt/my/dir` exists.

What other network connectivity needs to be in place for this to work? any ports besides ssh? any configuration/permission on remote host?

Google was no help when searching for mount per-requisites.

Comment: nfs ports, of course.... unless you're tunneling it over ssh.

Answer (score 0):

This is an **NFS** mount. It does not use **SSH**. On `serv_prod`, you need to make sure:

the NFS port (2049/tcp) is accessible through your firewall:

```
# iptables --list
# vim /etc/sysconfig/iptables
# /etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

you export `/mnt/my/dir`:

```
# exportfs -v
# vim /etc/exports
# exportfs -r
```

and the NFS service is running, of course.

Please Google for more details, but this is general formula.